# MQTT Communication Design between Multiple IoT Devices

Tags: mqtt, iot

I have this current setup:

Android app(ON/OFF button) <--> MQTT broker(mosquito) <--> NodMCU

MQTT TOPICS:

`cmd/light/power` - where my nodMCU receives ON/OFF command.
`status/light/power` - where my nodMCU returns the status of the load. This is where also the button status of the app is dependent.

The above setup works just fine and every time I add another IoT device I needed to change the mqtt topics inside the firmware before flashing to every iot device so i can control them individually and there where the problem comes in..

Maybe someone can guide me how to re-design my system that I can easily add new device to my android app and control them individually without changing the firmware of each IoT device? I'm trying to replicate the app eWeLink where it can easily add sonoff devices easily..

EDIT:
My thoughts:

- design the device firmware to generate unique ID for each iot device then the id should be included in the MQTT topic. then add the device to Android app using it's ID..

topic should look like this `cmd/<unique device id>/power` & `status/<unique device id>/power`

Comment: Since you seem to have answered your own question, add it as a proper answer rather than an edit

Comment: @hardillb, let say I've added hundreds of IoT devices and given the current solution I have. Does it mean all IoT devices will share single auth to access the broker?  I know it will work but I'm lacking of experience to see what future problems I will encounter..

Comment: That is a totally different question to the one you asked

Answer (score 1):

Design the device firmware to generate unique ID for each iot device then the id should be included in the MQTT topic. then add the device to Android app using it's ID..
topic should look like this `cmd/<unique device id>/power` & `status/<unique device id>/power`